# iOS 8 - UIPopoverPresentationController moving popover

Tags: popover, ios8

I am looking for an effective way to re-position a popover using the new uipopoverpresentationcontroller. I have succesfully presented the popover, and now I want to move it without dismissing and presenting again. I am having trouble using the function:

```
(void)popoverPresentationController:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController
      willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect
                           inView:(inout UIView **)view
```

I know it's early in the game, but it anyone has an example of how to do this efficiently I would be grateful if you shared it with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ive got the same problem.  Im also having a difficult time resizing the popover (it seems to be ignoring popoverLayoutMargins and popoverContentSize).  I get unrecognized selector when implementing _(void)popoverPresentationController:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect )rect inView:(inout UIView *)view_

I have set the delegate as per the docs, still no luck.

Comment: I figured that one out: set the size in viewWillAppear

Comment: Good call. my sizing is working still poking around at this delegate method...

Comment: @mehinger Did you ever figure out moving the uipopoverpresentationcontroller?

Comment: @Amendale I never did. Gave up and used a custom UIView instead

Comment: @mehinger yeah I resorted to the same solution...

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately this hacky workaround is the only solution I've found:

```
[vc.popoverPresentationController setSourceRect:newSourceRect];
[vc setPreferredContentSize:CGRectInset(vc.view.frame, -0.01, 0.0).size];
```

This temporarily changes the content size of the presented view, causing the popover and arrow to be repositioned. The temporary change in size is not visible.

It seems this is a problem Apple need to fix - changing the `sourceView` or `sourceRect` properties of `UIPopoverPresentationController` does nothing when it's already presenting a popover (without this workaround).

Hope this works for you too!

Comment: Same problem here , BUT in iOS7 no probelm!

Comment: This seems to still (2016, iOS 9) be the only way to make this work. You can set the the `preferredContentSize` back to it's original value, but you have to actually change it first, and it can't be to `CGSizeZero`.

Comment: Still needed (2017, deployment target iOS 9, SDKROOT iOS 11.2, Xcode 9.2).

Comment: aaaand to make matters worse, in iOS12 they've made preferredContentSize immutable so you can't even use this hack if you wanted to.

Answer (score 9):

I had luck using `containerView?.setNeedsLayout()` and `containerView?.layoutIfNeeded()` after changing the `sourceRect` of the `popoverPresentationController`, like so:

```swift
func movePopoverTo(_ newRect: CGRect) {
    let popover = self.presentedViewController as? MyPopoverViewController {
        popover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = newRect
        popover.popoverPresentationController?.containerView?.setNeedsLayout()
        popover.popoverPresentationController?.containerView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

And even to have a popover follow a tableView cell without having to change anything:

```swift
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "MyPopoverSegue" {
            guard let controller = segue.destination as? MyPopoverViewController else { fatalError("Expected destination controller to be a 'MyPopoverViewController'!") }
            guard let popoverPresentationController = controller.popoverPresentationController else { fatalError("No popoverPresentationController!") }
            guard let rowIndexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { fatalError("Expected sender to be an 'IndexPath'!") }
            guard myData.count > rowIndexPath.row else { fatalError("Index (\(rowIndexPath.row)) Out Of Bounds for array (count: \(myData.count))!") }
            if self.presentedViewController is MyPopoverViewController {
                self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false)
            }
            popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.tableView
            popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: rowIndexPath)
            popoverPresentationController.passthroughViews = [self.tableView]
            controller.configure(myData[rowIndexPath.row])
        }
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    }
}

// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

extension MyTableViewController {
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let popover = self.presentedViewController as? MyPopoverViewController {
            popover.popoverPresentationController?.containerView?.setNeedsLayout()
            popover.popoverPresentationController?.containerView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, setneedslayout and layoutifneeded worked like charm... you chown good knowledge

Answer (score 4):

I used the same method as mentioned in another answer by @Rowan_Jones, however I didn't want the popover's size to actually change. Even by fractions of a point. I realized that you can set the `preferredContentSize` multiple times back to back, but visually it's size will only change to match the last value.

```
[vc.popoverPresentationController setSourceRect:newSourceRect];
CGSize finalDesiredSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
CGSize tempSize = CGSizeMake(finalDesiredSize.width, finalDesiredSize.height + 1);
[vc setPreferredContentSize:tempSize];
[vc setPreferredContentSize:finalDesiredSize];
```

So even if `finalDesiredSize` is the same as your initial `preferredContentSize` this will cause the popover to be updated, even though it's size doesn't actually change.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for how to recenter the popover:

```
- (void)popoverPresentationController:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect     inView:(inout UIView **)view {

     *rect = CGRectMake((CGRectGetWidth((*view).bounds)-2)*0.5f,(CGRectGetHeight((*view).bounds)-2)*0.5f, 2, 2);
```

I have also used this method to ensure that the popover moved to the correct location after moving by setting the *rect and the *view to the original sourceRect and sourceView.

As an additional note, I don't believe that this method is called when the popover's source is set using a bar button item.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this because I don't have enough points to vote or comment. :)
@turbs's answer worked for me perfectly. It should be the accepted answer.

Setting *rect to the rect you need in the delegate method:

```
(void)popoverPresentationController:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController
    willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect     
        inView:(inout UIView **)view
```

Answer (score -1):

iOS 12.3

[vc.popoverPresentationController setSourceRect:newSourceRect];
[vc.popoverPresentationController.containerView setNeedsLayout];